# How to Mix Markers and Labels in Matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am working on a figure where space is constrained and I want to combine my legend using parentheticals as in this picture.

[image: Legend]

At the moment I just make some parenthesis in my labels for the plot and then edit the figure in Inkscape later on to add the missing markers, but this makes iterating on the plot more expensive in terms of time before having a usable figure.  Is there any way to hack matplotlib into doing something similar without having to go through an external program?

Comment: Check this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/userdemo/anchored_box04.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-anchored-box04-py